# German Weekday instead of english one, Dateformatter

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, date, swift4.2

how can i get weekday name but in german not in english. I tried this, but I can't get the german weekday.

```
func returnWeekDay() -> String? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyy"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "de_DE")
    guard let todayDate = formatter.date(from: returnFormattedDate()) else { return nil }

    let nameOfDay = formatter.weekdaySymbols[Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        .component(.weekday, from: todayDate)]
    return nameOfDay
}
```

Comment: try setting the `locale` of date formatter instead of timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date in Deutsch, use:

`formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")`